# Java Swing Redrawing (xPosition Trouble for Moving Objects)

Tags: java, swing

The problem I am having is when I move my "pieces", some of them get out of order (by that I mean their x positions are messed up) and I can not figure out why. I have tried adjusting the piece's sizes, tried changing the fill method in the Piece class, and tried adjusting the size of the JFrame. I'm going to provide a before, during, and after picture (Sorry I can not embed pictures yet), and all the code.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S3fR.png), [During](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A11L.png), [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCQwy.png). As you can see the "pieces" x-positions are off. The major things I could see being the problem would be: updating through an ArrayList of the Piece objects in my paintComponent method, the way I move the Piece object in its fill method This part I've tried changing -> (if(x<-100)), the actionTimer on a delay of 2ms which I've also tried changing to no effect, or maybe the way I create and add the "pieces". I'll also provide all my code [here](https://github.com/collin1158/roulette) in case that could help (and you could run it yourself).

My Roulette Panel Class: (I'm deleting some unimportant code out of these).

```
public class RoulettePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public ArrayList<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<Piece>();

private Timer actionTimer, rollerTimer;

private int yValue = 70;
private int actionCount = 0;
private int rollerCount = 0;
private int waitSeconds = 5;

public RoulettePanel() {

    start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(this);
    add(start);

    displayField = new JTextField(20);
    displayField.setEditable(false);
    add(displayField);

    addPieces();

    rollerTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayField.setText("Rolling in " + (waitSeconds-rollerCount) + "...");
            if(rollerCount==waitSeconds) {
                displayField.setText("Rolling...");
                rollerTimer.stop();
                playRound();
            }
            rollerCount++;
        }
    });

    actionTimer = new Timer(2, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            actionCount++;
            int velocity = 1;
            if(actionCount < 400) {
                velocity = 3;
            } else if(actionCount < 1600) {
                velocity = 2;
            }
            for(int i=0; i<pieces.size(); i++) {
                pieces.get(i).move(-1*velocity);
            }
            if(actionCount == 1900) {
                actionTimer.stop();
                determineWinner();
            }
        }
    }); 
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Color temp = g.getColor();

    for(int i=0; i<pieces.size(); i++) {
        pieces.get(i).fill(g);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(getWidth()/2, yValue-10, 2, 50);
    g.setColor(temp);

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if(source.equals(start)) {
        rollerCount=0;
        rollerTimer.start();
    } else if(source.equals(stop)) {
        actionTimer.stop();
        determineWinner();
    }
}

private void playRound() {
    actionCount=0;
    actionCount -= rand.nextInt(601);
    actionTimer.start();
}

private void determineWinner() {
    for(int i=0; i<pieces.size(); i++) {
        if(pieces.get(i).containsPoint(getWidth()/2)) {
            displayField.setText(pieces.get(i).toString());
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void addPieces() {
    int width = Piece.width;
    System.out.println(width);
    System.out.println(Main.GUI.getWidth()/15);
    pieces.add(new Piece(0, yValue, Color.GREEN));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width, yValue, Color.BLACK));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*2, yValue, Color.RED));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*3, yValue, Color.BLACK));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*4, yValue, Color.RED));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*5, yValue, Color.BLACK));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*6, yValue, Color.RED));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*7, yValue, Color.BLACK));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*8, yValue, Color.RED));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*9, yValue, Color.BLACK));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*10, yValue, Color.RED));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*11, yValue, Color.BLACK));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*12, yValue, Color.RED));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*13, yValue, Color.BLACK));
    pieces.add(new Piece(width*14, yValue, Color.RED)); 
}}
```

My Piece Class:

```
public class Piece {

public int x;
public int y;
public static int width = Main.GUI.getWidth()/15+6;
public Color color;

public Piece(int x, int y, Color color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
}

public void fill(Graphics g) {
    Color temp = g.getColor();
    g.setColor(color);
    if(x<-100) {
        x=Main.roulettePanel.getWidth();
    }
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, 30);
    g.setColor(temp);
}

public void move(int xAmount) {
    x += xAmount;
}

public boolean containsPoint(int x) {
    if(x>=this.x && x<=this.x+width) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String toString() {
    if(color.equals(Color.BLACK)) {
        return "Black";
    } else if(color.equals(Color.RED)) {
        return "Red";
    } else if(color.equals(Color.GREEN)) {
        return "Green";
    }
    return null;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}}
```

My Main Class:

```
public class Main {

public static JFrame GUI;
public static RoulettePanel roulettePanel;
public static Container pane;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GUI = new JFrame("Roulette");
    GUI.setSize(1005, 800);
    GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    pane = GUI.getContentPane();

    roulettePanel = new RoulettePanel();

    pane.add(roulettePanel);

    GUI.setVisible(true);

}}
```

Comment: Calling `repaint();` in `paintComponent` is not a good idea

Comment: Call `repaint` in the `actionPerformed` of the `Timer`

Comment: The problem seems to be associated with how you are handling the piece leaving the screen and been placed at the other end of the screen, it's taking into consideration the fact that the trailing piece isn't exactly at the edge of the screen any more and allows a drift to occur.